# Chain function call after function definition

Tags: function, coffeescript, chaining

How can I chain a function call after a function definition in CoffeeScript?

Equivalent javascript would be:

```js
var foo = function () {
    // stuff
}.bar()
```

The only way I managed to do it is:

```js
foo = `function () {
    // stuff
}.bar()`
```

But I hope for a better solution than embedding javascript in my (beautiful) coffeescript code

Comment: I have to wonder why the function itself would have a `bar` property. Was it supposed to be an IIFE? Did you adjust the prototype somewhere else?

Comment: @waleed-khan actually I'm defining an [Ember.JS](http://emberjs.com/) computed property, which is defined using: `fooBar: function() {}.property()` inside an `Ember.Object.extend`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
foo = (-> stuff).bar()
```

For example:

```
square = ((x)-> x*x).bar()
```

Compiles into:

```
var square;
square = (function(x) {
  return x * x;
}).bar();
```

Comment: I was so concentrated on putting `.bar()` after the `}` that I never tried to use parentheses. Thank you very much!