# Composing functions in a semi-ordered lattice shape

Tags: functional-programming, monads

I'm learning about monads, which, as I understand, work with a series of composed functions, encapsulating side-effects or contingencies that arise from some data values.

Is there an equivalent for a "semi-ordered lattice"?

What I mean is this.

Say I have some functions which are basically modelling the flow in a routing network.

Eg.

```
a = f(x)
b = g(x)
c = h(b)
d = i(c)
e = j(a,d)
```

etc.

Can something monad-like be used to manage possibilities of optional results, thrown errors or side-effects. j(a,d) is taking two of my "monadic values" ... eg. either of which Maybe nothing.

Comment: well yes to all - you can basically write just this in a haskell do-notation by just replacing `a = f (x)`  with `a <- f(x)` and the resulting computation will do what you asked (in the right monad) (of course you have to do the topological ordering yourself but you already did here)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chain function call after function definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894232/chain-function-call-after-function-definition)

Comment: @PaulSweatte I don't see why it's a duplicate. I'm not asking how to compose / chain functions. I'm asking how things like Maybe can be implemented / used when you have a lattice rather than a single chain.